# Neo4j https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am installing APOC for neo4j but can't find the `$NEO4J_HOME/plugins` folder on Windows 10. Neo4j 3.5.17 and Neo4j Desktop 1.3.8.

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/

My folder (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming) contains: Neo4j and Neo4j Desktop folder, none of which contains it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it here (Graph Database --> Open Folder).

[image]